# Не cрабатывает скрипт js

Tags: javascript, html

Есть скрипт

```
function MyFunction() {
    result = 0;
    firstQuestion1 = "Зеленая книга";
    if (document.test.firstQuestion.value == firstQuestion1) result++;
    document.getElementById('testResult').innerHTML = result;
}
```

Подключен к html документу

```
 <div class="firstDiv"  >
                        <textarea name="firstQuestion" cols="30" rows="5"></textarea>                  
     </div>
```

Пытаюсь вывести в элемент

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Проверить</button> 
<div class="anotherDiv" id="testResult"></div>
```

И ничего не происходит =(

---

Вариант воспроизводимого примера:

```js
function myFunction() {
    result = 0;
    firstQuestion1 = "Зеленая книга";
    if (document.test.firstQuestion.value == firstQuestion1) result++;
    document.getElementById('testResult').innerHTML = result;
}
```

```html
<form name="test">
  <textarea name="firstQuestion" cols="30" rows="5"></textarea>       
  <button onclick="myFunction()">Проверить</button> 
  <div class="anotherDiv" id="testResult"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: Приведите [минимальный воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: А `document.test` это у вас что?

Comment: @vsemozhebuty textarea находится в форме test

Comment: Тогда вам лучше всё-таки воссоздать тут сокращённый вариант разметки и скрипта с воспроизведением проблемы, как вас и просили, при помощи вставки кода, чтобы его можно было исполнить на вашей же разметке.

Comment: Я добавил в конец вопроса пример, как можно оформить воспроизводимый код. Как можно убедиться, он работает. Так что проблема, скорее всего, в чём-то, что вы пропустили в описании.

Comment: @vsemozhebuty спасибо большое. Ошибка была в теге <script></script>. Неправильно написал тег.

Answer (score 1):

Потому что `MyFunction` и `myFunction` - это разные вещи.

Comment: Не помогло. Попытался поставить на кнопку alert, тоже ничего не сработало